SOAP Webservice HTTPS request
I would like more informations about how to configure a server to test a SOAP request.
The webservice provider sent me two ".cer" files that I need to install in a apache server.
In my ssl vhost conf file I usually work with :
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/the-pem.pem 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/the-key.key

But how to configure with two .cer files instead ? OR add it to my trust store ?
For the moment I converted the two .cer files to .pem files, I added the content to the etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file which contains all certificates. Next I added
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 

to the apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
The message from the provider is :

The files “ca_etat.cer” and “ca_ircom_devl.cer” constitute the certificate chain allowing you to validate the WS responses in the
TEST environment. These files shall not be used to sign your requests,
however you should include the certificate chain in your trust
store.
In order to obtain an access in the TEST environment, you should
follow the WS access procedure that we sent to CEL on October 10th
2024 and provide us with a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file
following the requirements in Annex 2 of the procedure.
Based on the CSR, we will issue a certificate that you will sign your
requests with.

To be honnest I am umcomfortable with certificates, I do not know how exactly that works.
I also have to add a specific signature in the header of the request into a wsse security tag.
To globally explain, as a service provider, I developed a PHP Symfony app which need to send datas to the webservice every day. The client provide me an Apache LAMP server I have to use to communicate with a SOAP webservice. To do that I use the PHP Soap CLient -> https://github.com/phpro/soap-client. It's easy with a common soap webservice but in this case there is a lot of security :

IP restriction -> OK
HTTPS -> OK I guess (self-signed certificate)
certificates provided by the webservice provider : ca_etat.cer/ca_ircom_devl.cer but no key/passphrase. Normal ?
WSSE Security (header)
Operator ID (body) -> OK

Tell me if you need more informations.
Thanks by advance to help me about that.

I don't think you need to "configure your server" to test a call to a (remote) webservice. (the configuration you are showing seems to refer to an Apache server, but in that case it would mean that you are the service provider.. unless you are building some kind of proxy or
reverse proxy, but you need to give us more context if you need help on that).
To test a call against a WebSevice, you can use tools on the command line, such as curl.
You can find many examples on the web on how to use curl against a URL or SOAP WebService.
Examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222607/how-to-do-a-soap-wsdl-web-services-call-from-the-command-line)
You will need to add arguments to curl to point to the CA certificates the provider gave you (to automatically "trust" the certificates of the server you are going to connect to).
Examples here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879688/difference-between-cacert-and-capath-in-curl
If mutual authentication is required by the provider, you will also need to send them YOUR certificates (you can also test that using other curl attributes by sending your cert plus specifying its private key).

Thank you for your answer, today I will try to test it with curl from the server. I would like to test with SoapUI but there have an IP restriction.
I will take a look the links you sent me.
About the point Based on the CSR, we will issue a certificate that you will sign your requests with
Which kind of file it should be ? I have never had any key with certificates.

I "believe" they will send you a certificate (signed by their certificate authority) under the form of a PEM file (or CRT/CER) and you will need to use it to authenticate using it (as well as your private key). In theory, they will send you two certs. One for "you" (signed by their CA) that you will "send", as well as their "CA" certificate (called a trust or a CA cert). You will need to import "their" certificate in your CA certificates path to automatically "trust" any certificate you will see when you connect to their site (to automatically trust them since you trust "their CA")
